# PHP connection_aborted() and/or register_shutdown_function work intermittently

Tags: php

I've a PHP script that outputs a file to the user (as a download) which is also used to record what the user is downloading.

Basic structure is this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
register_shutdown_function('shutdown_fn'); //as a fail safe (i think)
//some other code here

//do some mysql queries

while(!feof($fh) && !connection_aborted()) {
    echo fread(....);
    ob_flush;
    ob_end_flush;
    sleep(1);
}
fclose($fh);

//do some more mysql queries here and set a boolean to track if it was done successfully

function shutdown_fn () {
    //check boolean to see if queries failed, if so, do them here
}
```

The above code seems to work 99% of the time just fine. However, there are some instances when the second set of queries don't execute at all (the other 1%). I have no idea why. The files being sent to the user range from very small to very large (and in both cases they work just fine so i cant see how a large file (or small file) would be breaking the code).

Any thoughts? I hope i have explained myself well enough

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Maybe it's simply killed after 30 seconds / http://de1.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time ?

Comment: set_time_limit(0); is already set in the actual code. But i'll have a look at the error log to see if some thing's acting up

Comment: @XonTaylor, hi Xon. have you got the answer? I have the same problem, but the solution already cost me a lot of time, but apparently I am making not much progress atm.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see some more code like the opening/reading of the file to further help you, but if you really want to be sure and not depend on the one shutdown_fn() function then why not call it yourself as well on the end of the script? Reset the boolean in the shutdown_fn() so whenever the actual shutdown is triggered than your sql queries are not ran twice.

Comment: The queries just before the shutdown_fn are exactly the same as those _in_ the function itself. The idea being if the script fails prematurely and the second set of queries fail to execute, then the shutdown_fn would do them. As for opening/reading file, i'm using the standard fopen/close before and after the while loop respectively. I hope i have understood you correctly.